# Proving analyticity, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

The full question is:
Prove that if $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates, then the functions $r^n$ $cos(n\theta)$ and $r^n$ $sin(n\theta)$, where $n$ is an integer, are harmonic functions of $x$ and $y$ (hint: Recall De-Moivre).

I have seen the proof of the question, and it involves saying "$f(z)=z^n$ ..., both $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ part are harmonic since the function $f(z)$ is analytic, I feel like I'm struggling with this, why is it so certain that $f(z)$ is analytic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to find the points on complex plane where $f(z)=z^n$ has singularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the exponential funtion $e^z$ is entire. Hence $f(z)=z^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$ is analytic function.

That is; $z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).$ So that 
$$\begin{align}
f(z)=z^n&=r^ne^{in\theta}\\
&=r^n(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n\\
&=r^n(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta)\\
&=r^n\cos n\theta+ir^n\sin n\theta\\
&=u(r,\theta)+i v(r,\theta)
\end{align}$$ 
Thus; $u(r,\theta)=r^n\cos n\theta,$ and $v(r,\theta)=r^n\cos n\theta$.

It is easy to show that $$u_{xx}(r,\theta)+u_{yy}(r,\theta) = 0$$
and
$$v_{xx}(r,\theta)+v_{yy}(r,\theta) = 0.$$
Hence, $u(r,\theta), ~and~ v(r,\theta)$ are harmonic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic and holomorphic are the same thing in complex functions. $f(z)=z^n$ is holomorphic with derivative $f'(z)=nz^{n-1}$. So it is also analytic. You can also see $z^n$ as a powerserie with all other coefficients zero, which also means it's analytic (analytic means that the function can be expanded into a powerserie)

Comment: And that shows that my function is analytic in the whole complex plane, right ?

Comment: Yes, $z^n$ is holomorphic/analytic in the whole plane